# Does an Uncaught TypeError in jQuery come from code conflict?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Tumblr's [login page](http://www.tumblr.com/login) is an inspiration for many, and as a hobbyist developer I was looking to see how they made their login form. I took away the superfluous code and came up with a simplified version, like so:

```
<div id="login_form_container">
    <form method="post" action="logged-in.html" id="login_form">  
        <div class="input_wrapper">
            <label for="login_email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="login_email" value="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"><span>Log In</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Seeing as I use **jQuery 1.3** on other pages, I tried using the following to get their nice effects. It's not quite how they have it, but a very simplified version:

```
<script>
$("input#login_email").click(function () {
    $(".input_wrapper").addClass("blurred filled");
});  

$("input#login_email").blur(function () {
    $(".input_wrapper").removeClass("blurred");
});
</script>
```

This works nice and dandy when this is the only code on the page, but when I put it in a page with other bits of jQuery, it returns an error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
    (anonymous function)
```

It's the same whether Chrome, Firefox or Safari, so it's clearly just my code.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

- Is it likely to be due to conflicting jQuery references elsewhere in the page (which all work fine)?
- Is it something more obvious?
- Is it because I haven't named the functions?

I'm puzzled as to why the code works in isolation but not when combined with other elements in a page. This has me stumped.

Comment: Is prototype *also* on your page?

Comment: You are correct sir. I did some hunting of my own to isolate the issue (see my comment to the first answer) and indeed there is a conflict arising from both Scriptaculous.js and Prototype.js - how might I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alter your script like this

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("input#login_email").click(function () {
    jQuery(".input_wrapper").addClass("blurred filled");
});  

jQuery("input#login_email").blur(function () {
    jQuery(".input_wrapper").removeClass("blurred");
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can also do something like this: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` this will assign the `$j` variable as the new jQuery function instead of the normal `$`. So you can do `$j('input#login_email')`

Comment: You should also note that you should import the jQuery framework before any other framework. And call the `jQuery.noConflict()` function before importing any other framework.

Comment: & @dan

The above do work in the sense they allow my login form to function, but they do stop seemingly all the others working. I also get the following error thrown up: 

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`

Which occurs for both prototype.js & controls.js (part of Scriptaculous)

Sounds like there might be bigger problems with my code and this issue is just highlighting that? Hm. Thanks for your responses

Comment: I have now solved the issue. Thanks to your comments and the jQuery documentation - http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries - I was able to sort this. As I had called the jQuery.js first, there was no need for the jQuery.noConflict(). Thank you all.